# Path finding algorithm on graph considering both nodes and edges

Tags: algorithm, path, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I have an undirected graph. For now, assume that the graph is complete. Each node has a certain value associated with it. All edges have a positive weight.
I want to find a path between any 2 given nodes such that the sum of the values associated with the path nodes is maximum while at the same time the path length is within a given threshold value.
The solution should be "global", meaning that the path obtained should be optimal among all possible paths. I tried a linear programming approach but am not able to formulate it correctly.
Any suggestions or a different method of solving would be of great help.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "linear programming"?

Comment: @WeaselFox, [linear programming on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)

Comment: Can you take loops, as long as the path length is with the threshold?

Comment: Do you know any limits about graph size and do you have restrictions with calculation time and memory?

Comment: What role does the edge weight play? You defined it but didn't use it. Also: did you mean "dynamic programming" instead of "linear programming"?

Comment: Two very important questions (they can determine if the problem is efficiently solvable). Can the path contain cycles? If yes, if a node appears twice in the path, does it get counted twice?

Comment: @watbywbarif: Size can be huge, graph can have hundreds of nodes. The algorithm should run in real-time

Comment: @hstoerr: edge weights are added to get the path length. I am interested in both dynamic and linear programming, any one is fine

Comment: @aelguindy yes the path can contain cycles, but a node appearing more than once is counted only once.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be perfect, but if the threshold value (T) is small enough, there's a simple algorithm that runs in O(n^3 T^2). It's a small modification of Floyd-Warshall.

```
d = int array with size n x n x (T + 1)
initialize all d[i][j][k] to -infty
for i in nodes:
    d[i][i][0] = value[i]
for e:(u, v) in edges:
    d[u][v][w(e)] = value[u] + value[v]

for t in 1 .. T
    for k in nodes:
       for t' in 1..t-1:
           for i in nodes:
               for j in nodes:           
                  d[i][j][t] = max(d[i][j][t],
                                   d[i][k][t'] + d[k][j][t-t'] - value[k])

The result is the pair (i, j) with the maximum d[i][j][t] for all t in 0..T
```

EDIT: **this assumes that the paths are allowed to be not simple, they can contain cycles.**

EDIT2: **This also assumes that if a node appears more than once in a path, it will be counted more than once. This is apparently not what OP wanted!**

Comment: What's the relation of this two : `d[i][k][t'] + d[k][j][t-t']`? what's the meaning of `d[k][j][t-t']`?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri d[i][j][k] is the maximum sum of vertex labels on a path between nodes i and j with a length of exactly k. d[i][k][t'] + d[k][j][t-t'] are two paths from i to k and from k to j. The first has length t' the second has length t-t', together they make a path of length t.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for an algorithm in general graph, your problem is NP-Complete, Assume path length threshold is n-1, and each vertex has value `1`, If you find the solution for your problem, you can say given graph has Hamiltonian path or not. In fact If your maximized vertex size path has value `n`, then you have a Hamiltonian path. I think you can use something like Held-Karp relaxation, for finding good solution.

Comment: I think that your reduction fails if the path is allowed to be not simple. I realize that OP did not mention what kind of path they're looking for, but I think it would be better if this point is made explicit in your answer.

Comment: @aelguindy, sure I wrote this for simple paths, but I don't know what's the opinion of `OP`, but normally when we talk about paths in graphs, we talk about simple paths (I refer you to any textbook in graph theory, first few pages says this). Also my reduction is for general graphs, but `OP` said his graph currently is complete, So I'm aware about all aspects, but I see OP looks for some linear programming, I thought it's better to introduce him/her to some related Linear programmings.

Answer (score 0):

Integer program (this may be a good idea or maybe not):

For each vertex v, let x<sub>v</sub> be 1 if vertex v is visited and 0 otherwise. For each arc a, let y<sub>a</sub> be the number of times arc a is used. Let s be the source and t be the destination. The objective is

maximize ∑<sub>v</sub> value(v) x<sub>v</sub> .

The constraints are

∑<sub>a</sub> value(a) y<sub>a</sub> ≤ threshold
∀v, ∑<sub>a has head v</sub> y<sub>a</sub> - ∑<sub>a has tail v</sub> y<sub>a</sub> = {-1 if v = s; 1 if v = t; 0 otherwise (conserve flow)
∀v ≠ x, x<sub>v</sub> ≤ ∑<sub>a has head v</sub> y<sub>a</sub> (must enter a vertex to visit)
∀v, x<sub>v</sub> ≤ 1 (visit each vertex at most once)
∀v ∉ {s, t}, ∀cuts S that separate vertex v from {s, t}, x<sub>v</sub> ≤ ∑<sub>a such that tail(a) ∉ S ∧ head(a) ∈ S</sub> y<sub>a</sub> (benefit only from vertices not on isolated loops).

To solve, do branch and bound with the relaxation values. Unfortunately, the last group of constraints are exponential in number, so when you're solving the relaxed dual, you'll need to generate columns. Typically for connectivity problems, this means using a min-cut algorithm repeatedly to find a cut worth enforcing. Good luck!

Comment: This looks good right now. I will analyse this and let you know if I have doubts

Answer (score 0):

If you just add the weight of a node to the weights of its outgoing edges you can forget about the node weights. Then you can use any of the standard algorigthms for the [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

Comment: But the graph here is undirected so then I would have to make it a directed graph. Secondly, the edge weight is the actual distance between the nodes and my path length depends solely on this distance. So if I add the node weights to its outgoing edges (assuming its a directed graph) then how do I ensure that the path length is within the threshold?

Comment: I will think about this approach. Let me see if I can restructure the problem